# Why @PostConstruct not invoked in spring container?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I tried to add some entities in the db shema

config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(ApplicationConfig.basePackage)
public class ApplicationConfig {
public final static String basePackage = "test"
}
```

spring container invocation:

```
public class StartApp {

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{

    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);

    TestEntityRepository repository = (TestEntityRepository) context.getBean("testEntityRepository");
    repository.save(new TestEntity("test"));
}

}
```

target class with annotation:

```
public class PersistenceService {

@Autowired
TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize(){
    //repository.deleteAll();

    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test1"));
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test2"));
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity("test3"));
}

}
```

as the result in table only one record - "test". At the Tomcat all works fine.

https://github.com/GlebSa/TestSpringJPA

Comment: How do you kno that the database only contains one record, since you seem to be using an in-memory, embedded database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `PersistenceService`is not recognized as a Service. Can you add the `@Service` to `PersistenceService`?

```
@Service
public class PersistenceService {
...
}
```

Hope this help.